# Trendline does not show up in plot (baseR)

Tags: r, trendline

I'm trying to create a trendline on a scatterplot using baseR. I used the `abline()` function. Upon executing, I did not encounter an error, but the trendline does not show up in the plot. Could it be because I plotted on a logarithmic scale?

```
IAA_M<-c(0, 1E-3, 1E-5, 1E-7, 1E-9, 1E-11)
gem_wortels<-c(7.71, 2.275, 6.34285, 4.71666, 8.36666, 4.822222)

plot(
  IAA_M,
  gem_wortels,
  ylim = range(c(
    gem_wortels - stdev_wortels, gem_wortels + stdev_wortels
  )),
  pch = 19,
  xlab = "[IAA] (M)",
  ylab = "gemiddelde wortellengte (cm)",
  log = 'x'
)
arrows(
  IAA_M,
  gem_wortels - stdev_wortels,
  IAA_M,
  gem_wortels + stdev_wortels,
  length = 0.05,
  angle = 90,
  code = 3
)
abline(gem_wortels ~ IAA_M,
       data_wortelgroei_regressie,
       lty = 3,
       col = 'red')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply an `lm` model to `abline`, not just a bare formula. However, you will need to use the `log10` value of your x axis on the right hand side of the formula in the model. Also, since the first value of your x axis variable is 0, the first row needs to be omitted, otherwise `lm` will throw an error since `log10(0)` is `NaN`.

Your example doesn't include the vector of standard deviations, so I have made one up for demonstration purposes:

```r
stdev_wortels <- c(2.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.1, 2, 1.4)

abline(lm(gem_wortels[-1] ~ log10(IAA_M[-1])),
       lty = 3, 
       col = 'red')
```

[image]